# Compare two dates and get difference in exact days, months, years, and more SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, function, date, date-difference

I am comparing two dates in SQL Server and need following information in precise manner:

Input:

```
Start Date = 12/28/2015
End Date   = 12/25/2020
```

Result returned (each piece in different column):

1. Days   = 1825 (includes start/end date in calculation)
2. Years  = 4
3. Months = 11
4. Days   = 28
5. How many days in Start Month = 31 days (Because it is December)
6. Occupancy in Start Month = (because December has 31 days, it would be 4/31) = .12903225806
7. How many days in End Month = 31 days (Because it is December)
8. Occupancy in End Month = (because December has 31 days, it would be 25/31) = .8064516129

Comment: So what is the problem? what have you tryed? SO isnt free code service. We help when you get stuck. Right now you havent show any effort. Those are basic time calculations you can find just goggle it `SQL day difference between 2 dates`

Comment: In point 3. How you get 11 months? point 4. How you get 28 days? In point 6. Where the `4/31` came from ?

Comment: @SalmanA That should be 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

For 1-3, you can check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp. It's fairly simple, you can just use `datediff` and specify the unit of interest.

For 4, you can simply do day(Start Date) to get the date.

For 5 and 7, you can use:
`SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@myDate)+1,0)`
to get the end of month date of the given date and use `day()` to get the day part of the datetime object.

For 6 and 8, it's just simple math, you get number of month in that month from 5 and 7, and then, if Start Date, then `(day(eom(Start Date)) - day(Start Date) + 1) / day(eom(date)` and if End Date, then `day(End Date) / day(eom(End Date))`.

I didn't give you the full code as I don't have SQL server running besides me. Hope it helps.